# CSS media query not hiding menu at 768px

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I am struggling to fix a bug in my wordpress and css coding.
I have created a footer and have applied a media query to hide it at (max-width:768px).
I have been following a course online, but some of the code that seems to work for him doesnt work for me, and this issues is really bugging me, so all help is much appreciated.

below if my footer code and css code:

Footer:

```
<footer class="site-footer container">
<div class="footer-content">

<?php
$args = array(
    'theme_location'=> 'main-menu',
    'container' => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'footer-menu'
);
wp_nav_menu( $args );
?>
<p class="copyright">All rights reserved . <?php echo get_bloginfo('name') . " " . date('Y'); ?> </p>
</div>


</footer>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
/*
Theme Name: Gym Fitness
Author: Luke Mersh
Description: Gym Theme
Version: 1.0
Tags: css grid, flexbox ready, mobile first, gym theme


*/
:root{
    --mainFont : 'Staatliches', cursive;
    --textFont : 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    --secondaryFont : 'Raleway', sans-serif;

    /**colours**/
    --primary: #ff5b00;
    --darkGray : #2f2e2e;
    --lightGray : #ebebeb;
    --white : #ffffff;
    --black : #000000;

}
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing:inherit;
}
body{
    font-family: var(--secondaryFont);
    font-size:1.6rem;
    line-height: 2;
}

/*headings*/
h1, h2, h3{
    font-family: var(--mainFont);
    margin: .5rem 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
h1{
font-size: 6rem;
}
h2{
    font-size: 4.8rem;
    color: var(--primary);
}

h3{
    font-size: 3.6rem;
}
/*globals*/
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.container{
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/* header*/
.logo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.site-header{
    background-color: var(--darkGray);
    padding: 2rem 0;
}
@media (min-width:768px){
.navigation-bar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
}
.main-menu{
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .main-menu{
        display: flex;
    }
    .main-menu .menu{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .main-menu li{
        margin-right: 2rem;
    }
    .main-menu li:last-of-type{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .main-menu a{
        color: var(--white);
        font-size: 2.8rem;
        font-family: var(--mainFont);
        padding: .5rem 2rem;
    }
    .main-menu .current_page_item{
        border-bottom: 3px solid var(--primary);
    }
    /**Mobile Menu**/
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .slicknav_menu{
            display: none;
        }
    }
    /**footer**/
    .site-footer{
        border-top: 2px solid var(--lightGray);
        padding:2rem 0;

    }
    .footer-content{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    /**footer menu**/
 .footer-menu .menu {
display: flex;
  }
.footer-menu .menu li{
      margin-right: 2rem;
  }
  .footer-menu .menu li: :last-of-type{
      margin-right: 0;
  }
 .footer-menu a{
font-family: var(--mainFont);
font-size: 1.8rem;
color: var(--black);

    }
  @media (max-width: 768px){
    .footer-menu .menu{  display: none;}
  }  





}
.copyright{
    text-align: center;
    flex:1;
    font-family: var(--mainFont);
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin:0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .copyright{
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using two `@media (min-width: 768px)`. So these are cancelling eachother out. Replace the one with the `display: none;` property on with `@media (max-width:767px)`

Comment: I will try that for sure, I thought that something was overriding the other - cheers

Comment: it doesnt work, I have been trying everything. I am using firefox broswer. any other ideas? I need someone to actually test the code. many thanks

Comment: It looks like nested media queries, actually. Close the second `@media (min-width: 768px)` for starters. (Add a closing curly brace before `/**Mobile Menu**/`.)

Comment: That code seems correct. many thanks, I have checked the curly braces and they seem all correct.

Comment: Thank you i found a missing curly brace from the media query (min-width:768px) right at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .main-menu{
        display: flex;
    }
    .main-menu .menu{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .main-menu li{
        margin-right: 2rem;
    }
    .main-menu li:last-of-type{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .main-menu a{
        color: var(--white);
        font-size: 2.8rem;
        font-family: var(--mainFont);
        padding: .5rem 2rem;
    }
    .main-menu .current_page_item{
        border-bottom: 3px solid var(--primary);
    }
} << missing this one
/**Mobile Menu**/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nesting issue in CSS you have to take following code out of the min-width media query

```
media (max-width: 768px) {
    .footer-menu .menu {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I found the issue was a missing curly brace at the end of the @media (min-width:768px)